# Confused about multinomials. Can we write $\binom{n}{a,b,c}=\binom{n}{a}\binom{n-a}{b}\binom{n-a-b}{c}$ if $a+b+c \le n$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, definition, multinomial-coefficients

Can we write $\binom{n}{a,b,c}=\binom{n}{a}\binom{n-a}{b}\binom{n-a-b}{c}$ if $a+b+c \le n$?

The definition for multinomial says $a+b+c=n$ must hold or else $\binom{n}{a,b,c}=0$.

I found that if $a+b+c \ge n$ we get $\binom{n}{a,b,c}=0$, but if $a+b+c \le n$, then $\binom{n}{a,b,c}=\binom{n}{a,b,c, n-(a+b+c)}$

Comment: You can write what you like but, as some others may be expecting something different, you should be explicitly clear what you mean and even then you may find it not worth doing.

Comment: Multinomials only are define for values that add up to the top. $\binom{n}{k,n-k},\binom{a+b+c}{a,b,c},$ etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for any $(a,b,c)\in\Bbb N^3$ and $a+b+c\leq n$ then,

$$\dbinom{n}{a}\dbinom{n-a}{b}\dbinom{n-a-b}{c}=\dbinom{n\qquad\qquad\qquad}{a,b,c, n-a-b-c}\;(n-a-b-c)!$$

*Unlike* the binomial coefficient, the *usual convention* is not to leave the last lower term of the multinomial coefficient implicit.   The sum of the lower terms is required to equal the upper term.

If you are using non-standard notation you should mention this somewhere (in your work).

Comment: Is there standard notation for something like $\binom{n}{a}\binom{n-a}{b}\binom{n-a-b}{c}\cdots$?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Why do you have a $(n - a - b - c)!$ appended to the rhs? I don't think it should be there. For example, if you calculate $\dbinom {6} {2,1,1,2}$, the lhs gives $180$ while the rhs gives $360$.